# How to set result for activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, preferenceactivity, startactivityforresult

I have a `ListActivity` that is started with `startActivityForResult` by a `PreferenceActivity`.

On `ListItemClick`, I want to return with a result to my `PreferenceActivity`.

How do I do this? When will `onActivityResult` be called?

Comment: As you `finish()`  **ListActivity**, the  `onActivityResult`  of **PreferenceActivity**. will be called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this on List Item Click Event.

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("SOMETHING", "EXTRAS");
setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
finish();
```